# Counting Inversions using merge sort - unexpected result

Tags: php, mergesort

This code produce correct result for small set of elements, but I don't know why the result is incorrect for large set of numbers (100,000 elements). For instance, this is [the 100,000 integers text file from coursera](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/IntegerArray.txt). I've already had the correct result from my python code. But I want to figure out why this php code is not correct.The output is 2397819672 intead of 2407905288.

```
$raw_input = file_get_contents($argv[1]);

$arr_input = explode("\n",trim($raw_input));

$count = 0.0;

function merge_sort($a)
{
    if(count($a) <2) return $a;
    $hl = count($a)/2;
    return merge(merge_sort(array_slice($a, 0, $hl)), merge_sort(array_slice($a, $hl)));

}

function merge($l, $r)
{
    global $count;
    $result = array();
    $i = $j = 0;

    while($i < sizeof($l) && $j < sizeof($r))
    {
        if($l[$i] < $r[$j])
        {
            $result[] =$l[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        else
        {
            $result[] =$r[$j];
            $count+= (sizeof($l) - $i);
            $j++;
        }
    }

    while($i <sizeof($l))
    {
        $result[] = $l[$i];
        $i++;
    }

    while($j <sizeof($r))
    {
        $result[] = $r[$j];
        $j++;
    }
    return $result;
}

$sorted = merge_sort($arr_input);

print $count . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a maximum integer value related issue, because I encountered this in python either.
I get the wrong answer 2397819672 (in fact I get to this page by google this number :) if the last part of my code is

```
f = open('IntegerArray.txt')
unsorted = list()
for line in f:
    unsorted.append(line)
merge_sort(unsorted)
```

I get the right answer 2407905288 if the last part of my code is

```
f = open('IntegerArray.txt')
unsorted = list()
for line in f:
    unsorted.append(int(line))
merge_sort(unsorted)
```

Can you find out the difference? That's where the answer lies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet you hit the maximum integer value in PHP.

According to the official documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

`The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.`

So you can change the int_max constant.

And something untested: Use it as a string.

Comment: I thought so, but the PHP_INT_SIZE is less than 2397819672. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: `PHP_INT_MAX` I think you need to check this constant

Comment: In my computer it is 2147483647 :-? but it is less than the false result

Answer (score 1):

Similar to one of the answer above, I was using Python.  The error is that your code is probably doing a string comparison instead of int comparison. For example, in Python, '33' < '4' is True.